# 404 Not Found Error when submitting form on website

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to build a contact form that uses bootstrap form HTML structure and PHP to control the backend validation and send the form information to my email.

Right now whenever I hit the submit button, I get a 404 Not Found Error which I assume has to do with the HTML not communicating the correct way with my PHP code. My website is 100% live (being hosted through NameCheap), and have been using cPanel's File Manager to upload all HTML, CSS, Image, and PHP files. I followed a Youtube tutorial on what the PHP should look like to validate my form's data and send it to my email.

I hadn't tried the $invalid_class_name aspect of the code yet, as I was trying to get the data to pass successfully first. I have the contact-form.php file in the same location as my HTML file, but I am wondering if I need to save my index.html file as a PHP file to make this work or an extra PHP plug-in on my website.

I have this PHP code included in HTML right above my form code

```
<?php 
      if($message_sent);
      ?>
      
        <h3>Thanks,we'll be in touch</h3>
      
      <?php
      else:
      ?>
```

HTML

```
<form name=”contact_form” action=”contact-form.php” method=”POST” class="row g-4">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="first-name" class="form-label">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="first-name" class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="John" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="last-name" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="last-name" class="form-control" id="last-name" placeholder="Smith" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email-address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label for="notes" class="form-label">Notes</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="notes" id="notes" rows="4" placeholder="Include any additional information"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="submit" class="pcs-cta-button form-submit-button">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

PHP

```php
<?php
$message_sent = false;
if (isset($_POST['email'])) && $_POST['email'] !='') {
  if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
    //submit the form
    $userFirstName = $_POST['first-name'];
    $userLastName = $_POST['last-name'];
    $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['notes'];

    $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $body = "";

    $body .= "From: ".$userFirstName." ".$userLastName "\r\n";
    $body .= "Email: ".$userFirstName. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Notes: ".$message. "\r\n";

    mail($to, $messageSubject, $body);
    $message_sent = true;
  }
  else {
    $invalid_class_name = "form-invalid";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: When the 404 page occurs, what is the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `”` instead of `"` in action of the `form` (and generally `form` attributes)

Change this:

```
<form name=”contact_form” action=”contact-form.php” method=”POST” class="row g-4">
```

to this:

```
<form name="contact_form" action="contact-form.php" method="POST" class="row g-4">
```

Now your browser tries to `GET` "`%E2%80%9Dcontact-form.php%E2%80%9D`" instead of "`contact-form.php`". And yes, it tries `GET` (default method) not `POST`, as your form method is invalid as well (same reasons - wrong quotation marks).

Comment: Thank you for that call out! I would have never noticed it. Now that I changed those quotes, the website tries to load the contact-form.php file and puts it at the end of my URL, but now I get a "This page isn’t working, proconcreteservicesllc.com is currently unable to handle this request, HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: error 500 in your case probably means that you got an error in your PHP script, check the server logs for more details or change the server configuration to display errors directly (not recommended for production environments)

Comment: For example your first `if` has wrongly placed brackets, should be `if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !='')) {` and not `if (isset($_POST['email'])) && $_POST['email'] !='') {`

Comment: This line: `$body .= "From: ".$userFirstName." ".$userLastName "\r\n";` has an error as well... missing `.` before `"\r\n"`, still this is a totally different question so if I helped in your current problem, accept an answer and ask another question.